# What happens to a Laravel DB Transaction if an exception is thrown?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I think* the transaction is just discarded. Is this accurate?

I'm using mysql

Example:

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    throw new Exception("something happened");
    DB::commit()
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::debug("something bad happened");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A transaction that isn't committed will be discarded in SQL.

When you throw the exception here, `DB::commit()` is never reached.  You'll go straight to the catch() block and therefore the transaction will be discarded (as long as `DB::commit()` isn't called somewhere later).

However, I would still always recommend explicitly rolling back the transaction in your catch block if you do not want to commit the transaction when an exception is thrown, this will close out that transaction and prevent any effect on your future queries in that execution.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    throw new Exception("something happened");
    DB::commit()
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::debug("something bad happened");
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

Or use the built in DB::transaction() with a closure to automatically rollback when an exception is uncaught, documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions

Comment: Thanks. does it hold on to the transaction and have some kind of cleanup process?

Comment: The transaction will be left open until the script is finished executing, at that time, there will be a clean up process that closes out / discards that transaction.  Because of that, I added my recommendation on explicitly rolling back the transaction when an exception is thrown.

Comment: can i use Db::commit as if to echo something if success execute

Answer (score 13):

If you are using in a Closure, like:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);
    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
```

You'll run this code inside framework:

```
public function transaction(Closure $callback)
{
    $this->beginTransaction();

    // We'll simply execute the given callback within a try / catch block
    // and if we catch any exception we can rollback the transaction
    // so that none of the changes are persisted to the database.
    try {
        $result = $callback($this);

        $this->commit();
    }

    // If we catch an exception, we will roll back so nothing gets messed
    // up in the database. Then we'll re-throw the exception so it can
    // be handled how the developer sees fit for their applications.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->rollBack();

        throw $e;
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $this->rollBack();

        throw $e;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So, in this case, you are 100% sure that the transaction is going to rollback. If you open manually transaction with `DB::beginTransaction();`, there is no way to be sure that is going to rollback, unless you make sure with something like:

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    //do something
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

If you throw an exception without catch, the scripts die or end with opened transaction, PDO will automatically rollback (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php):

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back.